# FragmentTransaction and Animation with a class that extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions

So in a layout I have three buttons, for control flow I am using a switch to determine what behavior occurs when each button is clicked.

My problem is, I want a fade transition to take over the default transition when each button is clicked to go to the next activity.

I think I have the code down, but when I run the emulator I don't see the transition change? I am new to Android and I do not know what I'm doing wrong, I attached my Java code and XML for the button layout and well as my in/out transition XML. Thank you!!

```
package com.example.jonathan.om11;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Jonathan on 12/28/17.
 */

public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button toEnv1Page;
    Button toEnv2Page;
    Button toEnv3Page;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

        toEnv1Page = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.envBtn1);
        toEnv1Page.setOnClickListener(this);

        toEnv2Page = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.envBtn2);
        toEnv2Page.setOnClickListener(this);

        toEnv3Page = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.envBtn3);
        toEnv3Page.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.envBtn1:
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.Env1Page");
                startActivity(i);
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fAnimation = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fAnimation.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                fAnimation.commit();
                break;

            case R.id.envBtn2:
                Intent ii = new Intent("android.intent.action.Env2Page");
                startActivity(ii);
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction f2Animation = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                f2Animation.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                f2Animation.commit();
                break;

            case R.id.envBtn3:
                Intent iii = new Intent("android.intent.action.Env3Page");
                startActivity(iii);
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction f3Animation = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                f3Animation.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                f3Animation.commit();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

LAYOUT XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jonathan.om11.MainTabbedActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/envBtn1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:text="Rainforest"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/envBtn2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:text="Desert"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/envBtn3"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:text="Fireplace"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

FADE IN ANIMATION XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0">

</set>
```

FADE OUT ANIMATION XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="500"
    >

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to `setCustomAnimations()` before `beginTransaction()` of fragments. Like,

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
             fragment.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
             android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             transaction.replace(R.id.your_layout_element_which_is_to_be_replace_by_fragment_layout, fragment);
             transaction.commit();
```

**Edit --** And if you also want to perform transition while navigating back from fragment then you just need to set `propEnter` and `propExit` transitions. For example,

```
fragment.setCustomAnimations(enterTransition, exitTransition, propEnterTransition, propExitTransition);
```

Comment: I just tried this, but then the compiler cannot resolve the symbol "f2Animation." Even when I start the class with:

`FragmentTransaction f2Animation;`

Unfortunately, the app broke when I clicked the button. :-(

Comment: Oh! Awesome, also should I make the screen I am transitioning to a fragment as well? Because I originally made it a FullScreen Activity.

Comment: No, you can easily clear fullscreen flags in your fragment. If you want

Comment: I'll be honest, I am so new I don't know what it means to "clear a flag." What does that mean?

Comment: I mean you can easily make default to your fragment from fullscreen easily.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained myself properly- the view I am transitioning to is a FullScreen Activity with it's own layout so when I try to do

`YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();`

the program raises a incompatible types error (required: "package", found:"Fragment".)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162659/discussion-between-heisen-berg-and-jonathan).